# How can I create an interactive list using MySql data in python

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, mysql-python

Im using Tkinter within my python code and rather than the code displaying a list of rooms available in the sites it displays a list which uses `Entry` causing the printed list to be changed rather than remaining fixed. Is there a way I can edit the code so it can print out a list of buttons I can select to open questions for that room.

```
sitename3_info = sitename.get()
# the label should print all of the rooms in the site that was inputted in the audit function
cursor = cnn.cursor()
# retrieves the siteID from the inputted site name
siteID_fetch2 = "SELECT siteID FROM Sites WHERE siteName = %s"
cursor.execute(siteID_fetch2, [sitename3_info])
siteID_fetch2 = cursor.fetchall()
print(siteID_fetch2[0][0])
# searches for all the rooms for the site that was inputted
room = "SELECT roomname FROM rooms WHERE siteID_fk2 = %s"
cursor.execute(room,[siteID_fetch2[0][0]])
printrooms = cursor.fetchall()
print(printrooms[0][0])
# prints out a list of rooms in the site
i=0
for rooms in printrooms:
    for j in range(len(rooms)):
        e = Entry(screen13, width=10, fg='blue')
        e.grid(row=i, column=j)
        e.insert(END, rooms[j])
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create buttons instead of `Entry` widgets:

```py
def action(room):
    print(room)
    # do whatever you want on the room

# assume OP code is inside a function
def search():
    sitename3_info = sitename.get().strip()
    if sitename3_info:
        with cnn.cursor() as cursor:
            # combine the two SQL statements into one
            sql = ("SELECT roomname FROM rooms, Sites "
                   "WHERE rooms.siteID_fk2 = Sites.siteID AND siteName = %s")
            cursor.execute(sql, [sitename3_info])
            rooms = cursor.fetchall()
        # remove previous result (assume screen13 contains only result)
        for w in screen13.winfo_children():
            w.destroy()
        if rooms:
            for i, row in enumerate(rooms):
                roomname = row[0]
                btn = Button(screen13, text=roomname, command=lambda room=roomname: action(room))
                btn.grid(row=i, column=0)
        else:
            Label(screen13, text="No room found").grid()
```

---

Update: example without using context manager:

```py
def search():
    sitename3_info = sitename.get().strip()
    if sitename3_info:
        cursor = cnn.cursor()
        # combine the two SQL statements into one
        sql = ("SELECT roomname FROM rooms, Sites "
               "WHERE rooms.siteID_fk2 = Sites.siteID AND siteName = %s")
        cursor.execute(sql, [sitename3_info])
        rooms = cursor.fetchall()
        # remove previous result (assume screen13 contains only result)
        for w in screen13.winfo_children():
            w.destroy()
        if rooms:
            for i, row in enumerate(rooms):
                roomname = row[0]
                btn = Button(screen13, text=roomname, command=lambda room=roomname: action(room))
                btn.grid(row=i, column=0)
        else:
            Label(screen13, text="No room found").grid()
```

Comment: Ive attempted to try your method however I receive the error: AttributeError: __enter__ Im not sure what would need to be changed in my code or whether I need to add anything to it.

Comment: with cnn.connect() as cursor:
AttributeError: '__enter__'

Comment: @Julia Then you have used a MySQL module not supporting context manager feature.  Answer updated with example without using context manager feature.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def change():
        global pos
        if j.get()==0:
            b2['state']='NORMAL'
            pos=0
        elif j.get()==1:
            b2['state']='NORMAL'
            pos=1
        elif j.get()==2:
            b2['state']='NORMAL'
            pos=2
        elif j.get()==3:
            b2['state']='NORMAL'
            pos=3
        elif j.get()==4:
            b2['state']='NORMAL'
            pos=4
    def dele():
        sql="""DELETE FROM myteam where Name = %s"""
        if pos==0:
          
            mycur.execute(sql,(name[0],))
        if pos==1:
            mycur.execute(sql,(name[1],))
        if pos==2:
            mycur.execute(sql,(name[2],))
        if pos==3:
            mycur.execute(sql,(name[3],))

        if pos==4:
            mycur.execute(sql,(name[4],))
        db.commit()
        messagebox.showinfo("ALERT","This player has been removed,select a new player")
        new.destroy()
    for i in range(0,len(name)):
        name[i]=name[i].strip("\'")
    for i in index:
        i = i.strip('\"')
        imgs.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(i)))
    j=IntVar()
    for i in range(0,len(index)):
        l2.append(Radiobutton(new,variable=j,value=i,image=imgs[i],state=ACTIVE,command = change))
```

This is a part of the code I used to select an image and delete that row from the table using the radiobutton feature, you can replace the delete function with whatever you choose to do with the button which is selected.